# Why direct access I/O works incorrectly with Intel Visual Fortran

Tags: compilation, fortran, intel-fortran, watcom

This program

```
  program test

  real a(10)

  open(1, file='f1',access='direct', recl=20)
  do i=1, 10
      a(i) = i-1
  end do
  write(1, rec=1)(a(i),i=1,5)
  write(1, rec=2)(a(i),i=6,10)
  close(1)
  open(1, file='f1',access='direct',recl=8)
  read(1, rec=4)(a(i),i =5,9,4)
  print*,a
  end
```

works incorrect in visual Fortran (incorrect):

```
  0.0000000E+00   1.000000       2.000000       3.000000       9.000000
   5.000000       6.000000       7.000000      0.0000000E+00   9.000000
```

Result in WATCOM (correct):

```
  0.0000000   1.0000000       2.0000000       3.0000000       6.0000000
  5.0000000   6.0000000       7.0000000       7.0000000       9.0000000
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default unit length of RECL in Visual Fortran is a word (4bytes). If you compile with option 'Use bytes as RECL= unit for unformatted file'    (/assume:byterecl), you will get what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to know when writing the code how exactly are the record long in whatever units. Setting `recl=20` or `recl=5` and depending on exact behaviour of your compiler and exact `real` size is a recipe for future problems.

You should ask the compiler for the size of the record in whichever units it uses:

```
integer :: recl5, recl2

inquire(iolength=recl5) (a(i),i=1,5)

open(1, file='f1',access='direct', recl=recl5)


...


inquire(iolength=recl2) (a(i),i =5,9,4)
open(1, file='f1',access='direct',recl=recl2)
```

Note: In Fortran 90 it could be much shorter by using subarray notation.

Note2: For some compilers your program will never work as the compiler is allowed to use record end marks into the file and you have to always open it with the same `recl`. But that is not common.