# Fortran write to binary:Fortran runtime error: Direct access data transfer requires record number

Tags: file, binary, fortran

My code

```
program v3

implicit none

real :: xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax,size
integer :: nx,ny,nz,i,j,nodestotal,sizeofinteger
real,dimension(:), allocatable :: v
integer,dimension(:), allocatable :: v1
integer,dimension(:,:), allocatable :: vel

sizeofinteger=2

open(unit=34, file='for.header', status='old')
read(34,115) xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax,size,nx,ny,nz
115   format(7f10.3,3i10)

nodestotal=nx*ny*nz
allocate (v(nodestotal))
allocate (v1(nodestotal))
allocate (vel(nx,nz))

open(unit=35, file='vel.txt', status='unknown')
read(35,*)v

v1=nint(v)

vel=reshape(v1,(/ nx, nz /) )
write(*,*)vel(:,25)

open(unit=36, file='vel.mod', form='unformatted', access='direct', recl=nx*nz*sizeofinteger)
do i=1,nx
write(36)vel(i,:)
end do 

end program
```

How to specify the record length?I have not worked with FORTRAN binary files for a long time.
What I really to write 601(nx) int 25(nz) times in binary file.I have changed sizeofinteger to 32.I want to write 2d array into binary file,should be simple.
Following Vladimir F's advise I have changed to stream accesss,but this is what I got
od -f vel.mod

```
1623500       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1623520               0               0               0               0
*
1625140       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1625160               0               0               0               0
*
1626600       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1626620               0               0               0               0
*
1630240       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1630260               0               0               0               0
*
1631700       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1631720               0               0               0               0
*
1633340       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1633360               0               0               0               0
*
1635000       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1635020               0               0               0               0
*
1636440       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1636460               0               0               0               0
*
1640100       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1640120               0               0               0               0
*
1641540       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1641560               0               0               0               0
*
1643200       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1643220               0               0               0               0
*
1644640       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1644660               0               0               0               0
*
1646300       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1646320               0               0               0               0
*
1647740       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1647760               0               0               0               0
*
1651400       8.688e-42               0               0               0
1651420               0               0               0               0
*
1653040
```

It should be 6200.Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very recently I said in an answer that people should not specify recl directly, but still so many do it... https://stackoverflow.com/a/37784431/721644

Use `inquire(iolength=myrecl)` as in that link and you will be much more portable.

Anyway, your code would be much simpler with stream access (resulting file is the same):

```
open(unit=36, file='vel.mod', form='unformatted', access='stream')
do i=1,nx
  write(36) vel(i,:)
end do 
close(36)
```

Comment: I have compiled code with stream access,still not working fine.Will edit again.

Comment: Without seeing the code no-one can say what is wrong. You should say what does your file dump mean and why you expect the value you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have already specified the record length in your `open` statement (the `recl` argument). The error is actually complaining about the `write` statement. In your `write` statement you need to specify which record you're writing, so you could use

```
do i=1,nx
  write(36,rec=i)vel(i,:)
end do
```

*Aside*

Note, as you are using `unformatted` the `recl` argument specifies the number of bytes per record.

The number of bytes per integer can be found using

```
sizeofinteger = storage_size(i)/8
```

and your record length would then be `recl=sizeofinteger*nz`.

*Update*

As has been pointed out in the comments by @IanH the `recl` argument is not always the number of bytes, it is in fact compiler dependent. As noted in the answer by @VladimirF one may determine the correct `recl` length an runtime using `inquire` to get the `iolength`.

Comment: I can compile with your suggestions and sizeof integer 32,but values are strange in vel.mod,something is wrong.Will edit my question.

Comment: @RichardRublev Storage size is numbers of bits. You would probably be better with stream access instead of direct anyway.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks I missed the divide by 8. As you say stream is probably the way to go.

Comment: @IanH Many thanks for this, one of the reasons I answer questions is to learn (although I of course try to ensure I'm correct first). I'm going to edit this into the answer as an update so that future readers are not misled by my original statement.