# read from text and write into binary

Tags: fortran

```
  INTEGER,PARAMETER :: nlv=6
   INTEGER,DIMENSION(nlv) :: aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg
   INTEGER::rec,irec
```

OPEN(50,FILE=test.txt',FORM='formatted',ACCESS='sequential',STATUS='old',ACTION='READ')

OPEN(60,FILE='test.bin',FORM='unformatted',ACCESS='direct',STATUS='unknown',recl=6*4,ACTION='WRITE')

DO K=1,6

```
  READ(50,76,err=97)aa(k),bb(k),cc(k),dd(k),ee(k),ff(k),gg(k)
```

76        FORMAT(i2,1x,i5,1x,i6,1x,i5,1x,i5,1x,i5,1x,i5)

```
  END DO


  WRITE(60,rec=irec)dd

  irec=irec+1
```

97        WRITE(* *)ERROR FOUND while reading data

```
  WRITE(*,*)"End of file found"

  CLOSE (50)
```

Comment: Tidy up your code so we can understand it more easily.  Make sure that it is a [mcve].  And tell us exactly what error message(s) you get.

Comment: please explain my problem

Comment: If anyone knows the answer, please respond.

Comment: @Deva You should first make the effort to tidy up your question. Half of your code is formatted as code, the other half is not. But foremost, you cannot just say *"it I am also getting error"*. You **must** give us the error message. You must exactly describe your problem. Now people are just guessing and that is not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that when you use direct access, the size of the record has to match or be bigger the size of data you are writing. You claim record length=6 (in bytes?), but you are writing 6*4bytes=24bytes.

Comment: Several compilers indicate the record size in words, not in bytes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898711/how-to-access-a-single-record-with-fortran-unformatted-direct-access-when-the-ap

Comment: yes, you are right, looks Intel FORTRAN goes with 4 byte and with assume byterecl compiler option for 1 byte. I use gfortran (f95), tested it, write works if record length>23. So for gfortran it is 1 byte.