# Fortran Direct Access Write and Read

Tags: fortran

This problem has been in my head for a while:
First I write a file here, ts0 is temperature values from 250 Kelvin to 300 Kelvin, and it is generated using equations in the same fortran file, but I'm only posting the write and read part:

```
   open(67,file=output3Dstr//'laststep_ts0',form='unformatted',access='direct',recl=8,status='unknown')
    irec10=1
    do i=1,nrow
    do j=1,ncol
    write(67,rec=irec10) real(ts0(n),8)
    irec10=irec10+1
    enddo
    enddo
```

Then I tried to read this file in Fortran using the same compiler and everything, (I used Matlab and can confirm it is good).

```
open(63,file=trim(laststepstr)//'laststep_ts0',form='unformatted',access='direct',recl=8,status='old')
irec10=1
do i=1,nrow
do j=1,ncol
read(63,rec=irec10) rtest
ts0(irec10)=rtest
irec10=irec10+1
enddo
enddo
```

When I print ts0(n), it gives me no meaningful results, it is totally not temperature values. I wonder, what is going on with this? I have tried playing with record length and format, it just doesn't work. Thank you for the help!!d

Comment: You should not be "playing" with the record length. The record length is not a number you should be controling. It is a number that you get from `inquire`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770912/why-direct-access-i-o-works-incorrectly-with-intel-visual-fortran  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898711/how-to-access-a-single-record-with-fortran-unformatted-direct-access-when-the-ap

Comment: Show us your complete code including all declarations of your variables. Show us your compilation commands and the complete output that gets printed. See [ask] and [mre].

Comment: This code is not compliant to the fortran77 standard, it requires at least fortran90. Edited accordingly

Comment: What is 'n' in your loop? Whatever it is it isn't getting incremented, so you could only ever get one distinct ts0(n) and you won't get any meaningful values unless n is in the index range of your array. Did you mean ts0(irecl0)?